# Hierarchical DataGrid Binding

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, datagrid, hierarchy

I've gone brain dead on this...

I have a class something like

```
public class STDMBaseItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public STDMItemCollection Items { get; set; }
    private STDMBaseItem Parent { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Parent == null)
                return Name;
            else
                return Parent.FullName + "/" + Name;
        }
    }

    public STDMBaseItem()
    {
        Items = new STDMItemCollection();
    }        
}

public class STDMItemCollection : ObservableCollection<STDMBaseItem> { }
```

I am able to display items in a tree view fine, that is not my issue...  I want to display it in a data grid with the columns:  Id, FullName, Details

Data might look something like (1 item in main collection and 1 item in child collection):

```
ID | Item Name          | Item Details
-- +--------------------+-------------------------
 1 | First Item         | Some Details
 2 | First Item/Child   | Some more details
```

The collection is named Items and is of type STDMItemCollection which has sub-items named Items of type STDMItemCollection (the same type)...

It seems like the XAML part should be simple, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: If you really want to display a hierarchical list as a flat structure in datagrid you would have to populate an observablecollection containing all these items as a flat structure. Meaning you would have to loop through all the children and add them to the collection which is bound to the datagrid.

Comment: I have it working that way...  just don't like the solution as it seems wasteful.  Thanks